# add numbers to specific observations

Tags: r, dataframe, padding

I have several IDs I am working with. I want to add a leading zero for values that have 1 integer after the dash in id. Here is sample data. I

```
id
2034-5
1023-12
1042-22
1231-9
```

I want this:

```
id
2034-05
1023-12
1042-22
1231-09
```

I tried this, but it's not working. Any advice?

```
x <-sprintf("%02d", df$id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually use `sub` here for a base R option:

```r
df$id <- sub("-(\\d)$", "-0\\1", df$id)
df

       id
1 2034-05
2 1023-12
3 1042-22
4 1231-09
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("2034-5", "1023-12", "1042-22", "1231-9"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `sprintf` you have to separate out both the numbers, use `sprintf` on second number and then combine them again.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(id, c('id1', 'id2')) %>%
  mutate(id2 = sprintf('%02s', id2)) %>%
  unite(id, id1, id2, sep = '-')

#       id
#1 2034-05
#2 1023-12
#3 1042-22
#4 1231-09
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `strsplit` and `sprintf` from `base R`

```
df$id <-  sapply(strsplit(df$id, "-"), function(x) 
        do.call(sprintf, c(as.list(x), fmt = "%s-%02s")))
df$id
#[1] "2034-05" "1023-12" "1042-22" "1231-09"
```